# Can connect to database with sqlplus directly, but not when setting ORACLE_SID

Tags: oracle, shell, unix, sqlplus, sid

I am trying to connect to a database in a shell script.  I can connect fine if I use this:

```
sqlplus user/pass@db_service_name
```

However, when I try something like this, it is not working:

```
ORACLE_SID=db_sid
export ORACLE_SID
sqlplus /nolog
connect user/pass
```

I get an error:

```
ERROR:
ORA-12545: Connect failed because target host or object does not exist
```

Obviously I am missing something, but this is an area I am not fully familiar with, so I am not sure where I am going wrong.  My assumption was that if I set the ORACLE_SID, that I would not need to identify my db when connecting in sqlplus.  Is my assumption incorrect?  Or am I missing some required step or configuration?

Comment: The reason I am doing it this way is that I want to store the connect script in a separate .sql file, so that I can use a connection script without having to know the actual user/password.  So the sql file would just have `connect user/pass`, and I could then call it in sqlplus `@/path/user.sql`.  So if there are alternatives (that do not require passing in the DB as an arg to the sql file), I would be open to those as well

Comment: It sounds like what you really need is an Oracle Wallet which are secure files for storing usercode/password combinations. Tim Hall has a good write up here: https://oracle-base.com/articles/10g/secure-external-password-store-10gr2 and the 12c docs are here: https://docs.oracle.com/middleware/1213/wls/JDBCA/oraclewallet.htm#JDBCA601 Oracle Wallets look complicated at first, but after you've used them a few times, they are easy to use and work with.

Comment: Could you possibly have TWO_TASK set and exported, to a TNS alias that has an invalid host name?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `sqlplus user/pass@db_sid` refers to a TNS alias in `$ORACLE_HOME/network/admin/tnsnames.ora`. If the instance is running on the same host as your sqlplus command, then you need to look at the text of the TNS alias in tnsnames.ora and set ORACLE_SID to the SID referenced in the file and then execute `. oraenv`. If the instance is not running on the same host as your sqlplus command, then your latter attempt will never work.

If you want more secure connections, you might consider using a wallet.